# Using border-box; with padding?

Tags: css, box-sizing

The reason why I’m asking is because there is
`padding: 25px;` added to it.

Is it a good idea here to add box-sizing or not?

Box-sizing **Removed**

https://jsfiddle.net/wby16ep8/1/

```
.container {
  width: 936px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  background: #000000;
}
```

Box-sizing **Added**

25 x 2 = 50 + 4 = 54 + 936 = 990

https://jsfiddle.net/wby16ep8/5/

```
.container {
  width: 990px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example of the HTML and include it in the question itself (using a stack snippet). The question needs to be self-contained. Currently there’s not enough context to answer this question without relying on a third-party source.

Comment: I just want to know if it is a good idea here to add box-sizing to the container, that's all. I provided links to the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rest of your code uses `box-sizing: border-box;`, use it here as well.

**Other Note**

If you want to support responsive design, yes.

Also, use the following code:

```
.container {
  max-width: 990px; /* Change */
  width: 100%; /* Change */
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you don't want to support responsive design, using `box-sizing` would just be a preference. Do you want the width to be included or not?

Comment: I'm not supporting responsive design, but all my other codes on the page are using border-box.

Comment: @MandyEvans If everything else uses it, then keep your code consistent and use it. I often use the following code: `* {  box-sizing: border-box;  }`